# Extract information on usage of functions and packages in R scripts

Tags: r, parsing, reflection, static-analysis

What would be a proper way to extract function calls and their occuring line in one or more R scripts? Is there a parsing base function or package that allows me to do this or should I build a solution with regular expressions?

For example:

```
function_calls("project1/exploratory_analysis.R")
```

should output a dataframe like:

```
##    function  line                filename
## 1    tapply    35  exploratory_analysis.R
## 2     qplot    80  exploratory_analysis.R
```

What I want to achieve finally is to build a reverse index of function calls and loaded packages as used in one or more R scripts, for educational and reference purposes. 
(e.g. used as a repository with examples of usage). For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------    
| function |       source_file      | line  |  package |
|:--------:|:----------------------:|:-----:|:--------:|
|  tapply  | exploratory_analysis.R |   35  |   base   |
|   qplot  | exploratory_analysis.R |   80  |  ggplot2 |
|    cor   |      regression.R      |   15  |   stats  |
|    cor   |      regression.R      |   27  |   stats  |
|  tapply  |      regression.R      |   12  |   base   |
| fromJSON |     load_dataset.R     |   5   | jsonlite |
|    %>%   |    transformation.R    |   10  | magrittr |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

One could use some regular expressions to extract function calls but I was wondering whether there exists a parsing, static code analysis or reflection facility supporting this task.

I suppose combining `parse()`, `substitute()`, `getParseData()`, `deParse()`, `srcfile()` (or maybe functions in the packages `mvbutils`, `codetools`) would make it possible, but I'm not familiar enough with their usage to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Are you talking about explicit calls to functions or would you include implicit calls (i.e., the call stack). Would you include functions such as `<-`, `if` or `*`?

Comment: @Roland I am mostly interested in explicit calls, since these are the ones most end-users would want to learn how to use. Regarding operators, I'm mostly interested in custom operators like the pipe operator `%>%` defined in `magrittr`/`dplyr`.

Comment: I just found out that `getParseData(parse("some_script.R"))` produces a `data.frame` with all the tokens, their type (symbol,function_call,expression etc.) and their line of occurrence. More specifically, `subset(getParseData(parse("some_script.R")), token == "SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL")` subsets the above data.frame to retain just the function calls. `token == "SPECIAL"` may be used to retain only special operators like `%in%` or `%>%`. If no one proposes a better solution, I will post this as an answer for anyone interested.

Comment: How would you then tie this to the package?