# determine which packages are used

Tags: r

Is there a quick way to scan an R script and determine which packages are actually used? By this I mean looking at all of the functions called in the script and returning a list of packages that contain these function names? (I know that function names are not exclusive to any one package)

Why not just look at packages called by `library()` or `require()`? Right. Well, I have a bad habit of loading packages I often use regardless of whether I actually use them in the script.

I'd like to clean up some scripts that I intend to share with others by removing unused packages.

I resolve to change my ways in 2016. Please help me get started.

**Update**

Some good ideas in the comments...

```
# create an R file that uses a few functions

fileConn<-file("test.R")
writeLines(c("df <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 1, 1), v2=c(1, 2, 3))",
             "\n",
             "m <- mean(df$v2)",
             "\n",
             "describe(df)  #psych package"),
           fileConn)
close(fileConn)

# getParseData approach
pkg <- getParseData(parse("test.R"))
pkg <- pkg[pkg$token=="SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL",]
pkg <- pkg[!duplicated(pkg$text),]
pkgname <- pkg$text
pkgname
# [1] "data.frame" "c"          "mean"       "describe"
```

**Update 2**

An ugly attempt to implement @nicola's idea:

```
# load all probable packages first
pkgList <- list(pkgname)
for (i in 1:length(pkgname)) {
  try(print(packageName(environment(get(pkgList[[1]][i])))))
}
```

It does not like the `c()` function, but the results seem otherwise correct.

```
#[1] "base"
#Error in packageName(environment(get(pkgList[[1]][i]))) : 
#  'env' must be an environment
#[1] "base"
#[1] "psych"
```

Comment: I hope this isn't pedantic, but: can you just manually uncheck all the packages in the Packages menu in RStudio... then run your script and see what functions it can't find? If you recognize "Oh, ```melt``` needs ```reshape2``` " then you can go in and load it at the top of your script.

Comment: Maybe `getParseData`, as outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33064376/324364)?

Comment: I'd try to determine the functions called in the script and then run over them `packageName(environment(function))` which should give the package of the function. Next, you can check the loaded packages and confront them to the actually used.

Comment: @nicola Sounds like the first part would be `getParseData` and then lookup the package name as you described...

Comment: Possible dupe: [How can I tell which packages I am not using in my R script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29415614/903061)

Comment: Thanks, @joran. I added an example using `getParseData()`. Trying to incorporate @nicola's `packageName()` idea. Yes, @Gregor, looks like a dup that I did not find. Thanks. Does not seem to have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: dumb question: `packageName(environment(mean))` will tell me that `mean()` is a function in the `base` package, and I can pass `pkgname[3]`, which is "mean", to `packageName(environment(pkgname[3]))`, but R evaluates `pkgname[3]` as a string...how to make R see mean as `mean`, not "mean".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer based on ideas in the question comments. The key functions are `getParseData()` and `packageName()`.

```
# create an R file that uses a few functions

fileConn<-file("test.R")
writeLines(c("df <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 1, 1), v2=c(1, 2, 3))",
             "\n",
             "m <- mean(df$v2)",
             "\n",
             "describe(df)  #psych package"),
           fileConn)
close(fileConn)

# getParseData approach
pkg <- getParseData(parse("test.R"))
pkg <- pkg[pkg$token=="SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL",]
pkg <- pkg[!duplicated(pkg$text),]
pkgname <- pkg$text
pkgname
# [1] "data.frame" "c"          "mean"       "describe" 

# load all probable packages first
pkgList <- list(pkgname)
for (i in 1:length(pkgname)) {
  try(print(packageName(environment(get(pkgList[[1]][i])))))
}

#[1] "base"
#Error in packageName(environment(get(pkgList[[1]][i]))) : 
#  'env' must be an environment
#[1] "base"
#[1] "psych"
```

I'll mark this as correct for now, but happy to consider other solutions.