# Get all sourced functions

Tags: r

In R, I am using `source()` to load some functions:

```
source("functions.R")
```

Is it possible to get the list of all functions defined in this file? As function names. (Maybe `source()` itself can somehow return it?).

PS: The last resort would be to call `source()` second time like `local({ source(); })` and then do `ls()` inside and filter functions, but that's too complicated - is there easier and less clumsy solution?

Comment: This doesn't use `source()`, but this [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064376/extract-information-on-usage-of-functions-and-packages-in-r-scripts) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I've checked the proposed solutions but that sounds way crazier than the last resort I presented in the question :)

Comment: I don´t know it this solution is crazier: `envir <- new.env() source("functions.R", local=envir) lsf.str(envir)`

Comment: Make a package out of your source files. Then you get all the advantages including a package namespace.

Comment: @TMS, misunderstood your question / did not read that you wanted *defined* functions. Apologies!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way would be to source the file into a temporary environment. Query that environment for all the functions, then copy those values to the parent environment.

```
my_source <- function(..., local=NULL) {
  tmp <- new.env(parent=parent.frame())
  source(..., local = tmp)
  funs <- names(tmp)[unlist(eapply(tmp, is.function))]
  for(x in names(tmp)) {
    assign(x, tmp[[x]], envir = parent.frame())
  }
  list(functions=funs)
}

my_source("script.R")
```

Comment: thanks, this solution looks promising, as the only one right now! Suprisingly, the one with least upvotes. It's the one I  mentioned as the last resort, but using `new.env()` instead of the elegant `local({ })` which I am not sure if it would work with the `assign` to the parent frame.

Comment: 1) do you think it would work with `local()`? And BTW, 2) what you do in the for loop: isn't there some function to merge environments?

Comment: @TMS It might work with local, though i've not tried it. I'm unaware of another way to copy all variables from one environment to another. It's not a common operation.

Comment: I think `attach` can be used to, well, attach one environment to another. Though you have to use the `pos` argument rather than specifying the `parent.frame`. And it will only work well for copying the whole environment, MrFlick's `for` loop lets you copy only the functions over.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit clunky but you could look at changes in the objects before and after the `source` call like this.

```
    # optionally delete all variables
    #rm(list=ls())

    before <- ls()
    cat("f1 <- function(){}\nf2 <- function(){}\n", file = 'define_function.R')
    # defines these
    #f1 <- function() {}
    #f2 <- function() {}
    source('define_function.R')
    after <- ls()

    changed <- setdiff(after, before)
    changed_objects <- mget(changed, inherits = T)
    changed_function <- do.call(rbind, lapply(changed_objects, is.function))
    new_functions <- changed[changed_function]

    new_functions
    # [1] "f1" "f2"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had this idea too but it doesn't work for very simple reason - if the package was already loaded (which happens all the time when I debug the code, I just re-source the sources), then it returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this regex catches almost every valid type of function (binary operator, assignment functions) and every valid character in a function name, but I may have missed an edge case.

```r
# lines <- readLines("functions.R")

lines <- c(
  "`%in%` <- function",
  "foo <- function",
  "foo2bar <- function",
  "`%in%`<-function",
  "foo<-function",
  ".foo <-function",
  "foo2bar<-function",
  "`foo2bar<-`<-function",
  "`foo3bar<-`=function",
  "`foo4bar<-` = function",
  "` d d` <- function", 
  "lapply(x, function)"
)
grep("^`?%?[.a-zA-Z][._a-zA-Z0-9 ]+%?(<-`)?`?\\s*(<-|=)\\s*function", lines)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
funs <- grep("^`?%?[.a-zA-Z][._a-zA-Z0-9 ]+%?(<-`)?`?\\s*(<-|=)\\s*function", lines, value = TRUE)
gsub("^(`?%?[.a-zA-Z][._a-zA-Z0-9 ]+%?(<-`)?`?).*", "\\1", funs)
#>  [1] "`%in%`"      "foo "        "foo2bar "    "`%in%`"      "foo"        
#>  [6] ".foo "       "foo2bar"     "`foo2bar<-`" "`foo3bar<-`" "`foo4bar<-`"
```

Comment: fyi I think this isn't really a **good** solution but it is definitely a *fun* solution. I would probably convert the file to a package if I really needed this information.

Comment: I have missed two edge cases! Functions can start with `.` and assignment functions (`\`foo<-\`<- function(x, value)` exist.

Comment: I use `=` for assignment, this won't catch any of my functions...

Comment: Good catch - edited. I will note that R lets you do silly things like `\` d d\` <- function(x)` which is currently not caught. I don't want the regex to get too silly, though I might revisit.

Comment: Also, you could assign functions with `assign`, `<<-`, and `->`. And it will be very hard to make this approach account for functions that are defined *within* functions, but aren't actually in the sourced environment. Your answer should work very well for standard cases, but you don't actually want to write an R parser out of regex.

Comment: @Gregor - how do you think I got these scars? :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is your own script so that you have control over how it is formatted a simple convention would be sufficient. Just ensure that each function name starts at the first character on its line and that the word `function` also appears on that line.  Any other use of the word `function` should appear on a line that starts with a space or tab.  Then a one-line solution is:

```
sub(" .*", "", grep("^\\S.*function", readLines("myscript.R"), value = TRUE))
```

The advantages of this approach are that

- it is very *simple*.  The rules are simply stated and there is only one simple line of R code needed to extract the function names.  Regex is also simple and for an existing file it is very easy to check -- just grep the word `function` and check if each occurrence displayed follows the rule.
- no need to run the source.  It is entirely *static*.
- *in many cases you won't need to change the source file* at all and in others there will be minimal changes. If you are writing the script from scratch with this in mind it is even easier to arrange.

There are many other alternatives along the idea of conventions. you could have a more sophisticated regex or you could add `# FUNCTION` at the end of the first line of any function definition if you are writing the script from scratch and then grep out that phrase and extract the first word on the line but the main suggestion here seems particularly attractive due to its simplicity and the other advantages listed.

### Test

```
# generate test file
cat("f <- function(x) x\nf(23)\n", file = "myscript.R") 

sub(" .*", "", grep("^\\S.*function", readLines("myscript.R"), value = TRUE))
## [1] "f"
```

Comment: `lapply(x, function(y) dostuff(y))` would break this

Comment: @alan ocallaghan, Your example violates the stated rules so it could not validly occur.  To write this and still stay within the rules one would have to start function on a new line that is indented or one could have to indent the lapply.

Comment: I think the utility is massively degraded if you require specific formatting, since that might require changing the file - in which case, you may as well suggest the user read the function names manually

Comment: That is only a consideration if you don't control the file but we have excluded that possibility.  Using conventions is very common in programming.  I often put `# TODO` throughout my code so I can grep my to do's, for example.  Another possibility along the same lines would be write `# FUNCTION` at the end of the first line of any function definition.

Comment: Another possibility would be to manually copy all the function names and paste them into a list, which would require about the same amount of work as the latter suggestion but doesn't really go with the spirit of the question.

Comment: @alan ocallaghan, In many instances the suggested convention requires no changes whatsoever whereas making an explicit list would require changes every time and would have problems in keeping the list and source consistent.

Comment: By definition the suggested convention (`# FUNCTION`) requires changes (and also requires that text to appear in no other context in the source files)

Comment: Of course. That is obvious but this was just an alternative and the main suggestion does not require any changes in many cases.

Comment: @TMS, It is not if you have a defined format like we have here.

Answer (score 0):

This adapts the code used in the post from my comment to search for a sequence of tokens (symbol, assignment operator, then function), and it should grab any defined functions. I am not sure if it is robust as MrFlick's answer, but it is another option:

```
source2 <- function(file, ...) {
  source(file, ...)
  t_t <- subset(getParseData(parse(file)), terminal == TRUE)
  subset(t_t, token == "SYMBOL" & 
           grepl("ASSIGN", c(tail(token, -1), NA), fixed = TRUE) & 
           c(tail(token, -2), NA, NA) == "FUNCTION")[["text"]]
}
```